# Can I make PyPDF2 fail gracefully when the PDF it is parsing is corrupted?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I have a Python application that scrapes hundreds of PDF files from public website and parses through them using this the python library [PyPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/)

Out of hundreds of such files that get parsed successfully, One file is giving me heartburn. It is 18 pages long. The filename is 'bad.pdf'. You can see it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11XTClwsCJVIc5CN-uYVma2h3sCc2i6y0).

This is my code that will parse through the document:

```
$ virtualenv my_env
$ source my_env/bin/activate
(my_env) $ pip install PyPDF2==1.26.0
(my_env) $ python
>>> import PyPDF2
>>> def parse_pdf_doc():
>>>     pdfFileObj = open('bad.pdf', 'rb')
>>>     pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
>>>     for curr_page_num in range(pdfReader.numPages):
>>>         print 'curr_page_num = {}'.format(curr_page_num)
>>>         pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(curr_page_num)
>>>         print '\tPage Retrieved successfully'
>>>         page_text = pageObj.extractText()
>>>         print '\tText extracted successfully'
```

When I run this code, it parses the first nine pages successfully. But then on the tenth page, it just hangs. Forever:

```
>>> parse_pdf_doc()
curr_page_num = 0
    Page Retrieved successfully
    Text extracted successfully
curr_page_num = 1
    Page Retrieved successfully
    Text extracted successfully
curr_page_num = 2
    Page Retrieved successfully
    Text extracted successfully
curr_page_num = 3
    Page Retrieved successfully
    Text extracted successfully
curr_page_num = 4
    Page Retrieved successfully
    Text extracted successfully
curr_page_num = 5
    Page Retrieved successfully
    Text extracted successfully
curr_page_num = 6
    Page Retrieved successfully
    Text extracted successfully
curr_page_num = 7
    Page Retrieved successfully
    Text extracted successfully
curr_page_num = 8
    Page Retrieved successfully
    Text extracted successfully
curr_page_num = 9
    Page Retrieved successfully
<... hung here forever ...>
```

What's the problem with page number 10? Let's open it in a viewer. Oh wow: Even Google Documents can't parse page #10. So there is definitely something corrupted about that page:

[image]

But still, I need PyPDF to throw an exception or fail in some other way, not just go into an infinite loop. It kills my workflow. What can I do to work around this corrupted page in a PDF file?

Comment: Try opening `thread` for every page. In `thread` you can pass the parameter of `timeout`.

Comment: (FYI only) I am stumped finding what's wrong with this file... My hand-written pdf checker warns of an object #925 that is referred to (which is out of range for the number of xrefs) but I cannot find what object is referring to this! An online PDF checker such as [DataLogics](https://www.datalogics.com/products/pdftools/pdf-checker/) happily reports that it contains no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Below template will give you an idea of how to achieve this.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
pdfFileObj = open('bad.pdf', 'rb')
for page in PDFPage.get_pages(pdfFileObj):
                    processTimeout = 20
                    extractTextProcess = Process(target=Function_to_extract_text, args=(pdfObject,page)
```

also `open` your file from `with` keyword (to save memory leak)

Comment: Where is `PDFPage` defined? And why is `processTimeout` assigned but never used? This answer seems a bit half-baked.

Comment: yeah, it's half-baked or rather just a template. you already have code you can implement.